# What's clang-format's equivalent to rustfmt's indent_style=Block?

Tags: c++, code-formatting, clang-format

If clang-format was rustfmt, it would have this all-encompassing [indent_style](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustfmt/blob/master/Configurations.md#indent_style) config option, which refers to this basic distinction in indentation style:

**Visual** (default in clang-format):

```cpp
ReturnType<std::vector<int>> ClassName::functionName(int a,
                                                     bool b,
                                                     float c,
                                                     double d,
                                                     long double complex e);

static const char* names[] = {"a",
                              "b",
                              "c"};
```

**Block** (default in rustfmt):

```cpp
ReturnType<std::vector<int>> ClassName::functionName(
    int a,
    bool b,
    float c,
    double d,
    long double complex e);

static const char* names[] = {
    "a",
    "b",
    "c",
};
```

How can I configure clang-format to do Block indentation in all syntactical scopes?

Or does any C++ formatter support Block indentation?

Comment: Here's a [`.clang-format`](https://gist.github.com/YodaEmbedding/c2c77dc693d11f3734d78489f9a6eea4) that tries to be Rust-like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What can be configured:

   (covers functions, ctor init lists and enums, but not lists)

   ```
   AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
   BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeComma
   BinPackArguments: 'false'
   BinPackParameters: 'false'
   ```

   The BinPack* options are not strictly there for the block indentation,
   but to do like the question shows and put either one or all items on the same line.
2. For lists, clang-format uses block indentation where postfix comma is used, and visual indentation where infix comma is used:

   ```
   static const char* postfixCommaDelimited[] = {
       "a",
       "b",
       "c",
   };
   static const char* infixCommaDelimited[] = {"a", "b",
                                               "c"};
   ```

   I think this makes sense if all infix comma delimited lists are one-liners,
   but I wish clang-format could do something about
   multi-line lists.
   Rustfmt rewrites them into postfix comma, which I would have liked in C++ too.

Answer (score 0):

The default style setting is Microsoft style (which aligns at the open paren). Use  `BasedOnStyle` set to `Google` to get the block indentation:

```
BasedOnStyle: Google
```

Comment: Are you sure? The nearest `BasedOnStyle` I could find was WebKit, but it doesn't break the line before the first element.

Comment: It works in the  simulator. Did it not work on your system?

Comment: Oh, it works in the simulator! But not with just `BasedOnStyle: Google` in a `.clang-format` file along with my example. It does something, though, like change indentation level from 4 to 2. My clang-format version is 10.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Uncrustify can do it, at least as far as you can find the corresponding option for each imaginable syntactical scope that C++ has to offer – I don't see any overall option.

For a start:

```
nl_func_def_start_multi_line = true
nl_func_decl_start_multi_line = true
nl_func_call_start_multi_line = true

nl_after_brace_open=true
nl_type_brace_init_lst_open = true
nl_enum_own_lines = add

nl_constr_init_args = add
pos_constr_colon = lead_break
pos_constr_comma = lead_break
```